# LinearLayout android orientation

Tags: android-linearlayout

### Heading ##I have one simple question.

I'm doing UI for the app.
I'm using a linearLayout, and to apply padding for my content, I'm using second LinearLayout inside the first o

So i found an xml example, But I can't understand why it is using two difrents orientation in Linearlayout?
So in the main Linearlayout orientation is set to horizontal, but in second linearLayout (which is inside the first one) orientation is set to vertical. And for me it is nonsense, why you should use a Horizontal orientation in main Linearlayout, if all content (buttons and textview) should be displayed only verticaly.

Thank you!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="30dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/main_title" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
android:textSize="24.5sp"/>
<Button
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in `linearLayout`, the programmer wanted to have `TextView` and `Button` beside each other in a same line.